# In Digimon, how could MagnaAngemon take down one Mega Level Digimon?

Tags: digimon

How could MagnaAngemon be strong enough to defeat one Mega Level Digimon when he's at the Ultimate Level?

As Angemon, he was able to defeat an Ultimate Level Digimon like Phantomon.

As MagnaAngemon, he was able to defeat a Mega Level Digimon like Piedmon and he has proven that he's strong enough to defeat BlackWarGreymon.

Comment: I feel like the last 2 lines were meant to be an answer. you're more than welcome to [self answer your own question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) but you'll need to edit the answer out of your question

Comment: Main protagonists plot powerbost aside (see Tai and Davis being stronger than average in their series) I think that what you noticed is part of a killed-of subtheme in the show. I fell like the two series were meant to include a more prominent "VS demon" plot. Think about it: first you have Angemon, then you get Kari who is depicted as more important than the other kids when she first join them (and she has another angel), at the same time Kari is haunted by demonic level forces beyond the digimon world. [cont]

Comment: If you remember, Digimon Adventure 2 has that very out-of-place episode about Kari falling in another layer beyond the Digimon realm: the Dark Ocean. And who saves her? Takeru. The whole episode has very prominent Lovecraft vibes and dialogues are heavily censored because of that in many countries. My theory is that the Cthulhu demon from this episode was meant to have a bigger role in the plot but the idea was axed as "too dark". Perhaps the Dark Ocean was meant to be the real cause of corruption in the Digimon realm, and that would explain the prominence of two "angel/holy" digimon...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Level is not the only deciding factor in a fight.

Although Digimon of the same level can be considered to be on par with each other in a general sense, there are exceptions. For example, [Lucemon](https://wikimon.net/Lucemon) is described as a Child (Rookie) Digimon with power greater than a Perfect (Ultimate) Digimon, while [Lucemon: Falldown Mode](https://wikimon.net/Lucemon:_Falldown_Mode) is an Ultimate Digimon with power exceeding Mega Digimon.

Although neither [Angemon](https://wikimon.net/Angemon) nor [MagnaAngemon](https://wikimon.net/Holy_Angemon) state in their Digimon Reference Book bios that they're particularly strong for their level, the descriptions do imply that their natures are oriented towards fighting evil.

Furthermore, the primary three [attributes](https://wikimon.net/Attribute) or types into which Digimon are classified are Data, Virus, and Vaccine. In the virtual pets, this is used as a sort of rock-paper-scissors mechanic, with Vaccine having an advantage over Virus. As one might infer, Angemon is Vaccine-attribute while [Phantomon](https://wikimon.net/Fantomon) and [Piedmon](https://wikimon.net/Piemon) are both Virus-attribute.

In conclusion, we can infer that Angemon/MagnaAngemon is intended to be more powerful than other Digimon of the same level, at least when fighting "evil"-natured Digimon.

Comment: Now that makes more sense. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 4):

The "levels" of Digimon are not directly related to their power.
This makes more sense in the Japanese version.

| Japanese | Kanji | English |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Baby | 幼年期 (Younenki) | Baby |
| Child | 成長期 (Seichouki) | Rookie |
| Adult | 成熟期 (Seijukuki) | Champion |
| Perfect | 完全体 (Kanzentai) | Ultimate |
| Ultimate | 究極体 (Kyuukyokutai) | Mega |

As you can see, a Digimon evolving is "growing up", not "getting stronger". Of course, the latter often comes hand in hand with the former.

But there are also different paths, as we saw in the anime with Skullgreymon.
Here's a reminder, both of these are level Adult:

| Numemon | Togemon |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

The level is not describing strength, but age. The game Digimon is based on is a raising sim. In a raising sim the goal is to get your character to a certain point before a time limit is up. When you do bad the character will age, but be weak and if you do good it will be a lot stronger before it reaches a certain age.

Comment: Hmmm.... I'm not sure how this answers my question, but thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: The premise of your question is not true. Levels do not imply strength. The stronger Digimon won, so there is no mystery.